# Ionic 4 firebase notification on tap redirection not working with this.ngZone.run(()

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic4

I am trying to redirect app to article when push notification comes and when app is in background. When some one tap on notification based on data received app sometimes redirect to article but sometime redirect to home page only.

I debugged code and found that code block always run correctly. "Navigation is successful" always print in console even when redirect to home page instead of notification page. On notification page I am fetching article content in ngOnInit function. Data successfully fetched from http api. It means page called but some reason does not render. I am totally blank what could be possible reason. Kindly help.

app.component.ts

```
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private storage: Storage,
    private toast: ToastController,
    public alertController: AlertController,   
    private menu: MenuController,
    private fcm: FcmService,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
  ) {
    this.user = {};
    this.initializeApp();
    this.backButtonEvent();
  }

  initializeApp() {
     this.platform.ready().then(() => {
     this.statusBar.styleDefault();
     this.splashScreen.hide();

     if (!navigator.onLine) {
        this.presentAlert('No Internet Connection','Sorry, No internet connectivity detected. Please reconnect and try again.');
     }   

      this.authenticationService.authenticationState.subscribe(state => {
       if (state) {
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
          console.log('App Component IF: '+state);
          this.router.navigate(['home']);
       } 

       if(state == false) {
         console.log('App Component ELSE: '+state);
         this.isLoggedIn = false;
         this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }   
       });  
       this.notificationSetup();
     });
   }

private notificationSetup() {
   this.fcm.getToken();
   this.fcm.onTokenRefresh();
   this.fcm.onNotifications().pipe(tap(msg => console.log(msg))).subscribe(
  (msg) => {
    if(msg.tap) {
      this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['notification', { id: msg.id, action: msg.action }])).then(e => {
          if (e) {
            console.log(e);
            console.log("Navigation is successful!");
          } else {
            console.log(e);
            console.log("Navigation has failed!");
          }
        }
      );          
    } else {         
      if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        this.presentToast(msg.aps.alert);
      } else {
        this.presentToast(msg.body);
      }
    }
  });
 }
```

Notification page notification.page.ts

```
export class NotificationPage implements OnInit {
  id: string;
  action: string;
  title: string;
  excerpt: string;
  content: string;    
  audio_code: string; 
  audio_link: string;
  type: string;
  section_parent: string;  
  section_slug: string;
  section_title: string;
  post: any;

constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, public api: RestApiService, public loadingController: LoadingController) { }

 ngOnInit() {
    //alert('Test');
    this.title = '';
    this.excerpt = '';     
    this.content = '';
    this.audio_code = '';        
    this.audio_link = '';        
    this.type = '';        
    this.section_parent = '';        
    this.section_slug = '';        
    this.section_title = '';        

    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.action = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('action');    
    this.getPost(this.id,this.action);
  }

  async getPost(id: any,action: string) {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create();
    await loading.present();

    await this.api.getArticleById(id,action)
      .subscribe(res => {
         console.log(res);
         this.title = res.object_title;        
         this.excerpt = res.object_excerpt;
         if(res.type=='video')
           this.content = res.video_link;
         else 
           this.content = res.object_content;
         this.type = res.type;        
         this.audio_code = res.audio_code;
         this.audio_link = res.audio_link;
         this.section_parent = res.section_parent;        
         this.section_slug = res.section_slug;        
         this.section_title = res.section_title;                  
         loading.dismiss();

       }, err => {
         console.log(err);
        loading.dismiss();
      });
  }
```

Comment: It seems to me "Navigation is successful" only means you went *somewhere*, not necessarily to the intended destination. If you log the `msg.action` does that always point to the proper article?

Comment: Yes, msg.action always point to correct article. Whenever it does not redirect to notification page. I checked log and found that article was properly fetched from api. I am calling getPost function from ngOnInit method on notification page. This function always run whether redirect to notification page or home page. There is no error and it works sometimes so i am totally clueless what is happening behind. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: @BenHulan I added notification.page.ts content in post details in case that help. Kindly review.

Comment: In that case I think the problem must be with the router. Are you using another navigation controller anywhere? Is it possible your article is rendered "beneath" the home page, as if home page is "pushed" on top of the nav stack? or that dismissing the loader or view is somehow getting called twice, thereby dismissing the loaded article before it renders?

Comment: @BenHulan Yes, In app.component.ts there is authentication check code. Based on login status user redirect to home page or login page. I updated full code above in post.

Comment: I think there is a conflict with your authentication service subscribing to state changes. I think you are successfully navigating to the article but at that moment the authentication service is subscribed to the state change and navigates you back to home, because `this.isLoggedIn == true`. It should log `'App Component IF: '+state` to the console, but if that happens before navigating, the page will reload and clear the log message.

Comment: It make sense. I will closely debug tomorrow and will let you know the results.

Comment: @BenHulan Authentication block. Every time App Component: null print in console in both cases. What I notice is when app not used for long time and if notifications comes. then first notification do not open. Notification after that open properly. Could it be somehow related to app state?

Comment: In that case you probably need to check for existence of data before running some logic, for example in notificationSetup(), `this.ngZone.run(() => { (msg.id && msg.action) ? //navigate : //don't navigate }`. I'm not sure which piece of data is missing

Comment: One more idea:  can you test with one hard-coded notification and see if it works?

Comment: I checked this part as well. Data exists as notification article data print in console when called from notification page NgOnInit method. There may be some delay in response from server sometimes. I will check with hard-coded notification.

Comment: @BenHulan I noticed another thing. When notification article open properly that time  notification opens quickly without splash screen. When Home Screen open that time  splash screen always opens.